# Populate an input field with an image src in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an XHR response that returns images. I have my function in order to show the images. I am combining JQuery and JS in the same code snippet. So far all is working well:

```
function resultat(o){  
          var leselements = o.query.results.bossresponse.images.results.result;
          var output = '';  
          var no_items = leselements.length;  
          for(var i=0;i<no_items;i++){  
            var lien = leselements[i].url;

            //place image urls in img src  
            output += "<img src='" + lien + "' class='imgs'>";  
          }  
          // Place images in div tag  
          document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;}
```

But I would like to allow users to click an image and then populate an input field ('#imageurl') with the clicked image src. Here is what I tried but it does not work.

```
$('.imgs img').click(function(){
            $('#imageurl').val() = "";
            var source = $(this).attr('src');
            $('#imageurl').val() = source;    
          });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 5):

Using .val() in this way will just return the current value of #imageurl.

```
$('#imageurl').val()
```

.val is a function call that works as a getter and a setter.

To set the value, try this:

```
$('#imageurl').val(source);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#imageurl').val("");
// ...
$('#imageurl').val(source);
```

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('img.imgs').click(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $('#imageurl').val(src);  
});
```

If the image will be rendered after the attachment of the event handler use this:

```
$('img.imgs').live('click', function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $('#imageurl').val(src);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your prompt answers. I tried all of them but they did not work for me. I then asked a friend and we finally found a way to make it work. Probably  not the best or professional way but it works. Here is the solution if ever anyone needs it.

```
function resultat(o){  
          var leselements = o.query.results.bossresponse.images.results.result;
          var output = '';  
          var no_items = leselements.length;  
          for(var i=0;i<no_items;i++){  
            var link = leselements[i].url;

//Place urls in image src and pass in 'link' parameter to the getsrc function 
            output += "<img src='" + link + "' onclick='getsrc(\""+link+"\")'>";  
          }  
          // Place images in div tag  
          document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;


        }

         function getsrc (link) {
            //console.log($(this));
            $('#imageurl').val("");
           // var source = $(this).attr('src');
            //place imageurl value by passing in the link parameter. 
            $('#imageurl').val(link);

          }
```